# css: display none. Is it expensive?

Tags: html, css

I decide to make ***read more...*** function by having two `div`s, and setting one of them `display: none`
but in this case i store all the data twice.
now the question -

---

If I have one div element, with `style="display:none"`, which contains many big size images in it, is it have an influence on page opening time?

Comment: For you sir, just £9.99. I accept PayPal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`display:none` does not prevent the hidden content from being loaded with the rest of the page.

If you want to make the page "lighter" at load time you can load the "read more.." content via Ajax on-demand.

Comment: @Diodeus but visually, when i try ti load the page, with extra big file in display:none div, it opens easally. why in this case?

Comment: If you're using FireFox, download and install the Firebug plug-in. The NET tab will show you what is being loaded with your page and how long it takes. You will be able to see it all for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The images would get fetched immediately even when the parent div is set to `display: none`.

If this is not your intention, and you do not want to go with the AJAX route, you may want to insert the images into the DOM only when the `read more...` button is clicked, as in the following example:

```
var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("your-hidden-div-id");
var imageToLoad = document.createElement("img");

imageToLoad.setAttribute("src", "image1.png");

hiddenDiv.appendChild(imageToLoad);
```

Comment: Actually, Opera doesn't load images if they are hidden, to save time on page load. But all the other browsers do AFAIK.

Comment: A better/easier solution is to have the image tags on the page, but have the src URLs in a different attribute, eg. `<img src="" rel="myimage.jpg">` and use javascript/jQuery to populate the src attribute when you're ready to load it.